# What design patterns should I be considering for this construction estimator project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, design-patterns

I should start by saying I'm a hobby programmer. I practice (mostly) PHP when I have breaks from practicing medicine and try to build on my knowledge over time while hopefully solving some problems for folks along the way.

Lately, I've been working on an application for my family's home improvement business.  The project is built on codeigniter and mongodb and, while it works, I know it isn't pretty.  I've spent some time reading about design patterns and am having a hard time deciding which one fits the 'estimator' portion of this project.

Here's how it works:

The user enters a series of measurements specific to a method of determining price.  Sometimes these measurements are specific to a type of product - gutters, for instance.  Other times, measurements are more closely related to the work being done than the product - covering exterior soffits with vinyl & aluminum, for instance.

All that's to say that each specific estimating method requires different *types* of measurements. Continuing with the two examples above...

To estimate gutters we must know, type(small, large, screen) and linear feet.  It's important to know that each type has it's own price associated with it.

To estimate soffits we must know linear feet only.

The estimate equation is rather easy - Quantity x Price = Estimate - but quantity could be # of pieces, # of feet, or # of square feet.

I wonder if I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be, but I'd like to take my skills to the next level and learn to design good, object oriented code. The next step in the project is to take these measurements and develop a list of materials needed for the job - a much more complicated endeavor due to the vast # of products available.

What design patterns should I be considering? So far I've looked mostly at `Abstract Factory`.  Should `Builder` be on my list? What else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just create a "Estimator" interface, have it require a method called Estimate(), and then extend that interface with a set of class, each one completing a different estimation.  They all would have a constructor that takes the input arguments (all information required for the estimation), and they all would impliment the estimate function, which would output the total cost.

Now I know you understand this pattern, because you list off patterns very similar to it.  I just want to show you how I'd code it, so you can see how it would work.  Sometimes even when it sounds like a bad idea, it turns out to work extremely well, and you just couldn't visualize it.

Something like:

```
interface Estimator
{
    public function Estimate ();
    public function BuildInfo ();
}

class Estimate_gutter implements Estimator
{
    private $totalLength, $gutterType;
    function __construct ($totalLength, $gutterType)
    {
        $this->totalLength = $totalLength;
        $this->gutterType = $gutterType;
    }

    function Estimate ()
    {
        return $this->totalLength * .45; // 45 cents a foot, consider a binary math library here though
    }

    function BuildInfo ()
    {
        return "Gutter Type: {$this->gutterType}, Length: {$this->totalLength}"; //to keep different classes from having to output different values, thus breaking the idea of abstraction we are trying to achieve; we'll just output a string that will be printed to the job list.
    }
}
class Estimate_sidewall implements Estimator
{
    private $width, $height, $type;
    function __construct ($drywallType, $width, $height)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->type = $drywallType;
    }

    function Estimate ()
    {
        return $this->width * $this->height * 1.12; // 1.12 a square foot, again consider a binary math library
    }

    function BuildInfo ()
    {
        return "SideWall type '{$this->type}' {$this->width}ft x {$this->height}ft = ". ($this->width * $this->height) ."sqft.";
    }
}

$gutter = new Estimate_gutter(100, "Type to gutter"); //pass this to the view

$gutter->Estimate(); //this would be run in the view, or be assigned in the controller to a variable for the view.  This must exist, because it is implementing the Estimator class.  The reason for this is so that you don't need to know what class type it is in the view, you just need to call the same function, no matter what.

/*
    This would print out all the information needed to retrieve
    the needed product.  It is important this function always returns
    the *exact* same data type every time for every class, otherwise
    the abstraction will break. (because if you output an array for one,
    and a string for another, how do you know when to deal with an array,
    and when to deal with a string? You'd need to know what type of estimate
    you're making, and you're attempting to eliminate needing to know that
    using this design pattern).
*/
echo $gutter->BuildInfo ();
```

Though I'd love to see other patterns and solutions to this problem, it isn't unique, but a good solution could be difficult to formulate.

Comment: This is a great example, @mazzzzz. Thanks. I think it will work beautifully for this portion of the project.

Follow up question: Another section of the project will be building a "materials list" that tells the work crew what materials they will need to complete the job. As an example, the amount of vinyl soffit that is needed for a specific job comes from several different measurements (and they appear as separate measurements on the estimate).  My question is this...If I define a class inside an `interface`, can I later use a function in that class to supply information to a `builder`?

Comment: There wasn't enough information for me to really formulate a reasponse to the follow up question (I don't quiet understand the goal you're trying to achieve).  If you want to, you could create another function in the interface (maybe call it BuilderInfo or something), and then implement that function in each of the classes, having them generate the information (sq ft, length, specific name, etc.).  I'll update my example to include that.